# Aggregating sales data

Tags: sql

I have a table the shows territory, year, month, and sales for each transaction.  I need to combine the transaction by month and territory, so it returns a list of monthly sales in each territory.  When I use the group by command it returns the following error message. 
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'sales.SalesTerritory.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT name as TerritoryName,
datepart(yy,soh.OrderDate)as Year,
datepart(MM,soh.orderdate) as Month, 
round(SubTotal,0) as SalesRevenue
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
inner join sales.SalesTerritory st
on soh.territoryID = st.territoryid
where datepart(YYYY,soh.OrderDate) = 2013
group by datepart(Month,soh.OrderDate)
```

Comment: As soon as you group things in SQL you can't just select a field because it doesn't know which one you want.  If there's multiple TerritoryNames grouped by date now .. which one do you want displayed?  You can group by that field making them all unique or you need to find another approach.

Answer (score 0):

All columns not mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause must be aggregated by any "aggregation function" like `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `AVG()`, etc.

In your case, I guess you forgot to add some columns in the `GROUP BY` clause at the end. I think it should look like:

```
SELECT name as TerritoryName,
datepart(yy,soh.OrderDate)as Year,
datepart(MM,soh.orderdate) as Month, 
round(SubTotal,0) as SalesRevenue
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
inner join sales.SalesTerritory st
on soh.territoryID = st.territoryid
where datepart(YYYY,soh.OrderDate) = 2013
group by
  datepart(yy,soh.OrderDate), -- added
  datepart(MM,soh.orderdate), 
  name -- added
```